# Unable to load realtime video feed from ip camera using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to access a live video feed from an IP camera, but whenever I try to run the code it gives me the following error.

```
warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:908)
warning: http://admin:Admin@123@192.168.1.188/video.cgi?.mjpg (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:909)
[ERROR:0] VIDEOIO(cvCreateFileCapture_Images(filename.c_str())): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(3.4.8) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:246: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): http://admin:Admin@123@192.168.1.188/video.cgi?.mjpg in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'
```

This is my code:

```py
import cv2

video = cv2.VideoCapture("http://admin:Admin@123@192.168.1.188/video")

while video.isOpened():
    _, frame = video.read()
    if frame is None:
        break
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitkey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have tried adding the port number, using RTSP but it still does not work.

When I add rtsp instead of HTTP I get the following error

```
[rtsp @ 000002bdf1e397c0] method OPTIONS failed: 404 Not Found
warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:908)
warning: rtsp://admin:Admin@123@192.168.1.188/1 (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:909)
```

the URL for rtsp I am trying is: `"rtsp://admin:Admin@123@192.168.1.188/1"`

Comment: it says `404 Not Found`. what does that tell you? your password also has an @ in it, which is supposed to separate user/password from host name, so that will be a problem too

Comment: further, I would recommend setting the apiPreference argument to VideoCapture to CAP_GSTREAMER or maybe CAP_FFMPEG since your first error indicates that CAP_IMAGES was tried automatically, which makes no sense for a network location.